# Excel 2002 Change R1C1 to A1B1

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel 2002. Something happened to my excel. The A1B1 is showing as R1C1 system. 
I want to change that back to A1B1. How do I change that?

Comment: I would suggest that you stick with R1C1 as it makes debugging spreadsheets so much easier. Understanding what "=J4+1" means requires knowing your current cell, but "=RC[-1]+1" does not. Also copied formulas do not change when moving from cell to cell in R1C1, yet they do in A1, so spotting an error is much much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your formulas have simply switched to the R(ow)/C(olumn) style.

I have no Excel 2002 installation present but in 2003 you can change the setting through: Tools->Options->General and unchecking the R1C1 Reference Style.

Based on the Screenshots on [jegsworks.com](http://www.jegsworks.com/Lessons/numbers/basics/step-options.htm) this should also work for Excel 2002.

The Microsoft Knowledge Base Article [regarding the R1C1 Format](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269866) also confirms that you should be able to access Options Through your Tools menu (apparently this goes even back to Excel 97).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the thing is I dont have "Options" under the "tools" menu. What can i do?

Comment: Thats weird. See my edit above. You should be able to access Options through Tools. Are you sure the Menu elements aren't hidden?

Comment: Sometimes, rarely used menu options are hidden. There might be a little double-down-chevron at the bottom of the menu. Click that and the menu will expand to its fullest, allowing you to choose "Options".